# My switch statement prints default everytime - It's a simple rock,paper,scissors game

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code - can anyone see, what I am executing wrong. If i use the 'win();' within function 'main' then the score updates, same with 'lose();' I am a beginner, only 3 months of practice so I can't see where I am going wrong. Can someone point the way. I have enclosed HTML, CSS and Javascript so you can see what each function should be doing.

```js
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let playerScore_span = document.getElementById("user-score");
let computerScore_span = document.getElementById("computer-score");
const scoreplace_div = document.querySelector(".score-place");
const rock_div = document.getElementById("ro");
const paper_div = document.getElementById("pa");
const scissors_div = document.getElementById("sc");

function win(player, computer) {
  playerScore++;
  playerScore_span.innerHTML = playerScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
}

function lose(computer, player) {
  computerScore++;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  playerScore_span.innerHTML = playerScore;
}

function draw() {
  console.log("draw");
}
let playerSelection;
let computerSelection;

function compChoice() {
  let computerMove;
  const words = ["ro", "pa", "sc"];
  computerMove = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  return computerMove;
}

function game(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  let computerMove = compChoice();
  switch (playerSelection + computerSelection) {
    case "paro":
    case "rosc":
    case "scpa":
      win();
      break;
    case "ropa":
    case "pasc":
    case "scro":
      lose();
      break;
    case "roro":
    case "papa":
    case "scsc":
      draw();
      break;
    default:
      console.log("it's fudged mate");
  }
}

function main() {
  rock_div.addEventListener('click', function(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    game("ro");
  })

  paper_div.addEventListener('click', function(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    game("pa");
  })

  scissors_div.addEventListener('click', function(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    game("sc");
  })
}

main();
compChoice();
game(playerSelection, computerSelection);
win(playerScore, computerScore);
lose(computerScore, playerScore);
```

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
}

.container {
  color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-2 {
  color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

span {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.game-hands {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 70px;
  p {
    border: solid;
    border-color: black;
  }
  .option-hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: white;
  }
```

```html
<title>Rock-Paper-Scissors</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<header>

  <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
</header>


<div class="score-place">

  <div id="user-label" class="badge">User</div>

  <div id="computer-label" class="badge">Computer</div>
  <span id="user-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
</div>


<section>
  <div class="container-2">

    <h1>Let's Play!</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="game-hands">
    <div class="option" id="ro">
      <img src="images/rock.jpg" alt="Rock">
    </div>
    <div class="option" id="pa">
      <img src="images/paper.jpg" alt="Paper">
    </div>
    <div class="option" id="sc">
      <img src="images/scissors.jpg" alt="Scissors">
    </div>
  </div>

</section>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="javascript.js">
  charset = "utf-8" >
</script>
```

Comment: The switch statement itself looks fine. I don't understand why you start the game in the on click event handlers AND also automatically after the setup? That direct call uses global variables which will be still undefined at that point.

Comment: Yes, as johey has stated, the initial switch statement receives playerSelection, computerSelection) both of which are undefined. Feels like you need computerSelection  = compChoice(); before calling game().

Comment: I'm not sure but wouldn't `Math.ceil()` make more sense than `Math.floor()`?

Comment: " I don't understand why you start the game in the on click event handlers AND also automatically after the setup? That direct call uses global variables which will be still undefined at that point. " - could you clarify a little more with an example in reference to the "automatically" please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as your problem is concerned

You used the parameter computerSelection that was not passed into the method, it will output the default string, which is normal, because there is no string that meets the conditions

According to the original conditions, the actual conditions will only have the following strings:

1. roundefined
2. paundefined
3. scundefined

But I see that your method has a computerMove parameter,
Combine my estimated logic and the internal logic of the program, the program should be adjusted as follows:

Replace `switch (playerSelection + computerSelection)` with `switch (playerSelection + computerMove )`

Comment: Thank you so much! it is now working. However, a new problem has occurred, it keeps displaying draw rather than win. I will try to problem solve this myself, it must be something simple that I am overlooking!

Comment: Okay, have a good day, and there will always be a tie. Except for luck, you can print the conditional parameters in the method, for example, const randomText = playerSelection + computerMove; console.log('randomText', randomText) ;